# strong tag not working in WordPress 4.0.1

Tags: wysiwyg

I want to display some content in my post as strong text. so i am change the content with WordPress WYSIWYG Editor but it not display as BOLD text only displays like normal text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Define bold and strong in your style.css file like this

```
b, strong {
        font-weight: bold;
}
```

then it display bold

Answer (score 0):

Amit Mishra answer is not working for me, but after adding !important it's worked well:

```
b, strong {
   font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

You can place it on your page css.